# Cronjob: fwrite in php

Tags: php, cron

I wrote that cronjob:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/ec2-user/neu/test.php >> /home/ec2-user/neu/log.log 2>&1
```

I used that code sample (test.php):

```
<?php
$filename = 'test.txt';
$somecontent = "Add this to the file\n";

// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
  if (is_writable($filename)) {

// In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
// The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
// that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
     echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
     exit;
}

// Write $somecontent to our opened file.
if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
    exit;
}

echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";

fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
 }
?>
```

But it doesnt work with the cronjob.

In the log file (log.log):

```
test.txt is not writable
```

Permission: -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 Jun  1 17:21 test.txt

However in the Terminal it does:

```
php test.php

[root@ip-172-31-39-112 neu]# php test.php
Success, wrote (Add this to the file
) to file (test.txt)[root@ip-172-31-39-112 neu]#
```

How do I solve that permission problem?

Thx

Comment: This will be answered over on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ But cron scripts have very limited permissions. You should use an absolute path outside of where cron is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding at the beginning of the script:

```
chdir("/home/ec2-user/neu");
```

Or use the absolute path to the file.

The cron job might be executed from another directory and the *test.php* file doesn't exist there.

If it still doesn't work check the selinux configuration if your computer has it installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_put_contents in php.
Refer:
a) https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_put_contents.asp
b) http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
<?php
$filename = 'test.txt';
$somecontent = "Add this to the file\n";
file_put_contents($filename,$somecontent, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

where mode FILE_APPEND will do like
If file filename already exists, append the data to the file instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Thx, but i guess the cron job was executed from another directory ;)